# C++ type casting between structures with different signatures in AIX

Tags: c++, casting, aix, reinterpret-cast

I have two structures:

```
typedef struct Struct1_t
{
  int a;
  uint b;
  int c;
}Struct1;

typedef struct Struct2_t
{
  uint x;
  uint y;
  int c;
}Struct2;

typedef Struct1 s1;
typedef Struct2 s2;
```

In a function I am using the type casting in the following way:

```
s2 func(Struct1 s1, uint id) {
return reinterpret_cast<s2> ((static_cast<uint> (reinterpret_cast<uintprt_t> (s1))) + id);
}
```

This compiles fine in Linux and Windows 64-bit environment. But in AIX it still shows a warning message:

> Pointer type "s2*" and type "unsigned long" are not compatible in the current aliasing mode

I know that I am casting between two incompatible types and even tried a bit of workaround for example:

```
s1* s1_p = &s1;
s2* s2_p = reinterpret_cast<s2*> (s1_p);
return *s2;
```

but to no avail.

Comment: You are violating a strict aliasing rule and compiler doesn't like it. Do not do this.

Comment: You're deep in undefined-behavior land. If you're going to do it anyway, ignore the warning.

Comment: @PeteBecker, I had my dealings with AIX compiler. If xlC tells you you shouldn't do something, you really should not. The program won't behave.

Comment: @SergeyA -- yes, you've grasped the nature of undefined behavior. Thank you for your input.

Comment: There is no way you can even guarantee that both structs will be the same size.  This should be avoided like the plague.

Comment: I am porting a project into 64 bit environment that was written almost 20 years ago and they wrote the function body in this way: `return (s2) ((ulong) s1 + id );` The policy was not to change api and any other logic/design but in this case I am assuming I do have to change the design.

Comment: You must change design, otherwise you'll need to watch carefully for sizeof Struct(s), fields order, alignment and so on. This is undefined behaviour -- according to my experience.

Comment: @PeteBecker, what I am trying to say is that it's worse than undefined behaviour. After all, one can carefully study what particular implementation does on particular system, make sure it fits the bill and use undefined behavior. Not unheard of inside, for example, really low-level OS drivers - which are not portable at all. But in this case it is worse. It is almost guaranteed to fail.

Comment: Once more: uint (whatever it is) not guaranteed to be able to hold a pointer. Use uintptr_t (works in any platform) or ulong (work in unix (which is LP32 or LP64)).